# Entity Framework compare two data sets

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a situation where I need to compare two sets of data from Sql Server. One set of data is held in a table (which is modelled in my Entity Framework model), however the other is the result set of a stored procedure. The fields returned by the stored procedure are identical to the fields in the table.

I had thought the following would work:

```
using (var db = new MyDatabaseContext()) {
    DbSet<MyTable> tableData = db.MyTables;
    DbSet<MyTable> procData = db.Set<MyTable>();
    procData.AddRange(db.MyTables.SqlQuery("exec dbo.MyProc").ToList();

    if (tableData.Count != procData.Count) return false;

    foreach (var data in tableData) {
        if (!data.Equals(procData.Find(data.ID))) return false;
    }
}
```

(side note: The `MyTable` class has been edited to implement `IEquatable` and override `Equals` so it's suitable for comparing at field level)

The logic being that I believed `db.Set<MyTable>` would create an arbitrary empty set of `MyTable`s which I could populate with the result of the stored procedure, and then compare that to the data in the table.

It appears I've misunderstood this, however, as checking the contents of `tableData` and `procData` at the first `if` line shows both contain exactly the same data (I've purposefully editted the stored procedure so it does not return the same data as in the table), leading me to believe that `db.Set<Table>` and `db.MyTables` both reference the same thing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What could make them different (i.e. what is being "filtered" in your stored procedure), wouldn't it be easier to check for matches to any of those criteria?

Comment: Essentially, I have tables that contain snapshots of various `sys` tables, and the stored procedures return the actual current content of the `sys` tables. As tables get added/changed, the `sys` tables will obviously look different to the snapshots. I want to compare these and flag up differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.MyTables` has the same definition as what is returned in the line defining `procData` and initially contains the same objects.

(I assume your DbContext has the following, or something equivalent):

`public DbSet<MyTable> MyTables { get; set; }`

Calling `db.Set<MyTable>()` will give you a set equivalent to the property defined on the context.

If you are simply filtering in the stored procedure then `tableData` contains all records (so does `procData`). When you attempt to add more records (which are ostensibly the same records contained in the set), [EF will try and add the records with a state of "Added"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). The thing is, your comparison isn't testing for the difference in state, and EF might not consider them added (if you configured your primary keys just so, EF might determine that the records already exist and state changes are unnecessary).

Comment: Cheers. I was completely barking up the wrong tree. Giving it some more thought, doing the comparison on Sql Server instead (which makes infinitely more sense!)